# Asterisk Music On Hold

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I need help I have an asterisk and I need to play music on hold and a parallel execut macro

```
same => n,Dial(SIP/${pbx}/#5147582218943,60,M(booms),m(mymoh))
```

M(booms) identify if he answered the call
m(mymoh) music on hold but it didn't work

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If MoH works then the ```default``` class is playing with ```m``` or ```m()``` or ```m(default)```. Did you try that? Another way to test MoH is in ```waitexten(7200,m)``` for the ```default``` class and 2h (7200s) music.

Comment: ...and whatfor stands ```${pbx}``` ? Normaly it is ```${EXTEN}``` without ```/#5147582218943```

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this:

```
same => n,Dial(SIP/${pbx}/#5147582218943,60,M(booms)m(mymoh))
```